# Not able to get value from form handler to jsp

Tags: jsp, atg

I am sending List from form handler to jsp using set Attribute method.When i directly pass to for each droplet it works perfect.but if i am using getvalueof tag in jsp.Then i am not getting value.

There is another problem.If i used same for each droplet twice in my jsp.The results are only shown in my first jsp .

Please help me in debugging and finding solution for this.

Comment: If you can't fix the problem having the code in front of you, how can we help without seeting anything?

Comment: More details required or your answer will just be a guess...

Comment: When you say 'using the set attribute method', do you mean you are invoking the request.setAttribute() method from within your form handler? This is not the standard ATG pattern. You should expose the value as a bean property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a multitude of reasons why this doesn't work so without the code I can only point out the obvious mistakes that people usually make:

Correct:

```
<dsp:getvalueof var="somelist" bean="formhandler.list" />
```

Incorrect:

```
<dsp:getvalueof var="somelist" param="formhandler.list" />
<dsp:getvalueof var="somelist" value="formhandler.list" />
```

Perhaps output the value of `somelist` in your JSP page to see if it does get set?

As far as your list being used in multiple JSPs. Again I have to guess. If this is an embedded JSP then you need to remember to pass the `list` to the included page:

```
<dsp:include page="some-embedded-page.jsp>
    <dsp:param name="somelist" value="${somelist}"/>
</dsp:include>
```

If this is a new JSP page all together, perhaps change your formhandler scope to `session`. But don't just change it. Make sure you understand the impact of formhandler scope (as it *almost* always should be request).